# Output form data to file in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am simply trying to output some form data to a text file. I cannot get it to work. Can anyone help with this? I get an error `invalid offset type`. Thanks for all the help!

here is the php

```
$file = "output.txt";

$current = file_get_contents($file);

foreach ($_POST as $key) {
    $current .= $_POST["data"][$key];
}

file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

and here is the html

```
<form name="input" action="getinput.php" method="post">
  Name: <br /><input type="text" name="data[]" placeholder="First and Last"><br />
  ID: <br /><input type="text" name="data[]" placeholder="Your ID"><br />
  Major: <br /><input type="text" name="data[]" placeholder="Your Major"><br />
  Email: <br /><input type="email" name="data[]" placeholder="Email Address"><br />
  Phone: <br /><input type="text" name="data[]" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX"><br />
  Addition Information: <br /><textarea name="data[]" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Please enter any extra  or comments you would like me to have or know."></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
   $current .= $value;
}
```

Right now you are looping through the entire `$_POST` array not only the part containing your `$_POST['data']`, which is the reason why you get an `Invalid offset` warning when doing:

```
$_POST["data"][$key];
```

Comment: @KristerAnderson I still get a warning saying ` Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` it does post to the file. is there any way to also format the output so it looks nicer?

Comment: @zachstarnes - If you still get an `Invalid offset` warning then I think you're doing something else wrong. The above should work as long as your data is really posted to the page.

Comment: @kristenanderson I no longer get that warning. I get a new one that says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and the data DOES post to the page :)

Comment: @zachstarnes - Try doing a `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` in you array to see what it actually contains.

Comment: @kristenanderson for some reason after i put the code snippet in an if statement it went away! i put it in a `if(isset($_POST['data']))`

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` isn't right. You want something like this to output the **values** and not the **key**

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $value) {

    $current .= $value;
}
```